# Как после создания shared_ptr передать ему указатель?

Tags: c++

Как после создания shared_ptr передать ему указатель?

```
std::shared_ptr<Investment> createInvestment()
{
   std::shared_ptr<Investment> retVal(static_cast<Investment*>(0),
   getRidOfInvestment);
   // как тут передать в retVal указатель.
   return retVal;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared

Comment: `tr1` не нужен, вместо `static_cast<Investment*>(0)` можно писать `nullptr`

Comment: Книга была написана еще тогда, когда `shared_ptr` был только в проекте в `tr1`. Возможно, тогда все было еще несколько по-другому.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас странная функция, но если уж очень нужно, то можно воспользоваться функцией `reset`:

```
retVal.reset(newInvestment, getRidOfInvestment);
```

Comment: зачем тогда Маерс передал указатель на функцию чистильщика при создании пустого смартпойнтера?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете создать умный указатель [`shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) двумя способами: 
1) вызывать конструктор shared_ptr, передавая указатель на готовый, уже сконструированный объект, который он контролирует

```
std::shared_ptr<Investment> retVal(new Investment());
```

2) воспользоваться специальным методом [make_shared](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared), который создает объект типа T и возвращает "умный" указатель данного класса.

```
std::shared_ptr<Investment> retVal = std::make_shared<Investment>();
```

Comment: мне не понятно зачем Маерс в своей книге "Эффективное использование C++. 55 верных
способов улучшить структуру и код ваших программ" в правиле 18  нарисовал такую конструкцию.

Comment: Может быть у меня старое издание, но у меня в 18 главе нет такого кода. Как называется правило?

Comment: Правило 18: Проектируйте интерфейсы так, что их легко
было использовать правильно и трудно – неправильно

Comment: на самом деле, в этой главе описывается, что умному указателю можно привязывать свою функцию, которая занимается удалением объекта. Но есть также рекомендация, **Конечно, если указатель, которым должен управлять pInv, можно было бы определить до создания pInv, то лучше было бы передать его конструктору pInv вместо инициализации pInv нулем с последующим присваиванием значения**. А чтобы привязать умному указателю объект, вы можете, либо создать новый объект умного указателя и присвоить его существующей пустышке. Либо вызвать метод reset, передавать указатель на сконструированный объект.

Comment: для чего пустому смартпойнтеру(пустышке) функция чистильщик? бред какой то.

Comment: @StanislavPetrov, этот код действительно выглядит глупо, но Вы учитывайте главу, в которой это описано. Он же там прямо говорит, что это глава не по `shared_ptr`, а по интерфейсам. Правда, это всё равно не оправдывает такого кода, он мог использовать пример получше.